# How to access/reference DLL in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dll

Is it possible to reference a DLL (made from C# or C++) in PHP using CodeIgniter Framework?
 If yes, how?
 I'm gathering info, I've also asked the CodeIgniter forums. :D

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You are trying to access "application" written in different language.
Maybe you should give us more info, what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I'd like to create a library that is either accessible/reusable by ASP and/or PHP... rather than creating 2 separate libraries - maintaining both libraries would realy be tedious.

Comment: I see... haven't tried ASP.NET yet. I guess I'm referring to ASP.NET. If then, is it possible for PHP to access a DLL?

Comment: Did you read my answer? I told you that it is not posible, why are you asking again the same question? If you haven't tried ASP.NET yet, simply do it in PHP.

Comment: haha.... because you were asking for additional info. I was thinking, maybe the answer will be different. ok, that's fine. thanks.

Comment: Additional info = new info. And I was also asking for other thing - if you like my answer, mark it like accepted answer (and maybe you should do this with your other questions).